# Unable to set color of UIViewController navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm presenting my view controller with the following code:

```
UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sessionController];
[self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

from within the presented view controller "viewDidLoad" method I'm attempting to set the navigation bar color with the following, but I am not successful:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UINavigationBar.appearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

The navigation bar color will NOT change from white.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Note: I am not using story boards or XIB files.

Comment: you can try to set your change in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Add this Line `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to change the background color:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: That kind of worked but for some reason now self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height reports the height to be twice the size it actually is.

Comment: @user3335999 do you mean the height is twice the actual size after setting this?

Comment: Yes, the height is twice the actual size after setting this.  The bar paints at the correct size but the frame.height says its twice the size it paints the bar.

Comment: The problem shouldn't be related to this change. Maybe you're customizing the height somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation controller object create when applied the color. Like this below example.

```
UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sessionController];

navigation.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navigation.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navigation.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];


[self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

And below this method all navigation controller change color.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```